# Why doesn't Java have a putIfAbsent(key, supplier) method in Map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I just recently found myself wanting a version of putIfAbsent(...) in java.util.Map that you can supply some kind of factory method to, to instantiate an Object if it's not already present. This would simplify a lot of code.

Here is my modified interface:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

/**
 * Extension of the Map Interface for a different approach on having putIfAbsent
 * 
 * @author Martin Braun
 */
public interface SupplierMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {

    public default V putIfAbsent(K key, Supplier<V> supplier) {
        V value = this.get(key);
        if(value == null) {
            this.put(key, value = supplier.get());
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Now my question:
Is there another (easier) way of doing this or have I just overlooked something in the Java API?

Comment: FWIW, [`Map#putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) was added with Java8.

Comment: in Java 1.8 there is V putIfAbsent(K key, V value)

Comment: I know, but it only allows to provide a Object instead of a Supplier method.

Comment: what's wrong with above code. I think it should work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Isn't [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) what you want?

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is
>   mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping
>   function and enters it into this map unless null.

Implementation is something like:

```
if (map.get(key) == null) {
    V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
    if (newValue != null) {
         map.put(key, newValue);
    }
}
```

So it's not exactly the `Supplier<V>` signature you've posted but close to that. Having key as argument in the mapping function definitely makes sense.

Comment: Ah. I overlooked that one. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep. The key as argument makes more sense, that's right. I will accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Any solution for Java 7 users?

Comment: @shlatchz Not with standard Map.

Comment: @lexicore, so Android programmers don't have any other way to do this?

Comment: @shlatchz I don't know Android APIs that well but I think the whole `Function` and `Supplier` is first available in Java 8. You can of course write wrapping code or use some other collection libraries. But the standard Map does not have this functionality pre-Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

**computeIfAbsent** is not a 1:1 replacement for **putIfAbsent** because constraints for the returned value do not match. While **putIfAbsent** returns **null** when a new entry is created, **computeIfAbsent** always return the assigned value.

A default implementation as suggested above with a call to **get** and then **put** works, but it requires two lookups in the map, which destroys the idea of a performant in-situ replacement.